# Getting the average of filtered Positive + Negative numbers in Haskell

Tags: haskell

So I'm trying to take in a list of numbers and return the average of the non-negative numbers minus the average of the negative numbers.

This is my attempt at it and I'm not sure if I'm going about this the completely wrong way. If anyone can point me in the right direction, that'd be appreciated.

```
filNeg :: [Int] -> [Int]
filNeg [] = []
filNeg xs = filter (<=0) xs

filPos :: [Int] -> [Int]
filPos [] = []
filPos xs = filter (>0) xs

average :: [Int] -> Int
average [] = []
average x = sum filNeg/length filNeg - sum filPos/length filPos
```

And the errors

```
PosNeg.hs:10:14:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’ with actual type ‘[t0]’
    In the expression: []
    In an equation for ‘average’: average [] = []

PosNeg.hs:11:17:
    Couldn't match type ‘[Int]’ with ‘Int’
    Expected type: [Int] -> Int

      Actual type: [Int] -> [Int]
    In the first argument of ‘sum’, namely ‘filNeg’
    In the first argument of ‘(/)’, namely ‘sum filNeg’

PosNeg.hs:11:44:
    Couldn't match type ‘[Int]’ with ‘Int’
    Expected type: [Int] -> Int
      Actual type: [Int] -> [Int]
    In the first argument of ‘sum’, namely ‘filPos’
    In the first argument of ‘(/)’, namely ‘sum filPos’
```

Comment: Two things: (1) you aren't using `x` in your function (2) Haskell division is a bit different from other languages. If you want an `Int` output, you'll  need to use `div`

Comment: I have this as now as a change 

average = sum filNeg div length filNeg - sum filPos div length filPos 

Getting this as an error, sorry I'm new to haskell so wrapping my head around this.

PosNeg.hs:10:1:
    Equations for ‘average’ have different numbers of arguments
      PosNeg.hs:10:1-15
      PosNeg.hs:11:1-69

Comment: @Fergus2k8 The issue isn't to get rid of the `x` from the function, it is to use it. It is the argument to your function (the list of `Int`s), so you should use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first error, `average` cannot return `[]` on an empty input; it has to return an `Int`.

The other two errors occur because you are treating `filNeg` and `filPos` as lists, not functions that return lists.

```
average :: [Int] -> Int
average [] = 0
average x = sum (filNeg x) `div` length (filNeg x) - sum (filPos x) `div` length (filPos x)
```

To use `div` as an infix operator, you need to enclose it in backquotes.